# Como adicionar a uma Form um array de ficheiros?

Tags: php, javascript, html, http, input

Fiz um pequeno script para fazer upload de imagens de forma a possa escolher quantas quiser. No fim fica um array com toda a informação. Como posso fazer com que esse array com os ficheiros vá no request para no backend poder inserir na BD?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostre o HTML de como vc fez isso. É um file multiple?

Comment: Sim, sempre que o valor do input muda eu passo tudo para um array para ter controlo dos ficheiros. Mas agora não sei como enviar esse array no request